# ECO A03 Bird's opening Dutch Variation for analysis

Tags: opening, analysis, birds-opening

Here is fen diagram of end game,

```
[fen "3Qk2r/B1p2pp1/p7/4P2p/P4P2/2P4q/2r4P/R2R2K1 w k - 0 1"]
```

I tried few games with Bird's opening today.

> Chess.com says `Bird's Opening Dutch Variation` in fact for this game.

The other games has much blunders. Here is the good one, but somewhat straight forward however representable, however so, I say,- I mean not much development principles followed. However as start of, here is the one for analysis which bounds `ECO A03`

```
[fen ""]
[ECO "A03"]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.03.13"]
[White "anandsadasivam"]
[Black "skenderaliu"]
[WhiteElo "798"]
[BlackElo "769"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[Result "1-0"]
[Termination "anandsadasivam won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "3Qk2r/B1p2pp1/p7/4P2p/P4P2/2P4q/2r4P/R2R2K1 b k - 0 19"]

1.f4 d5 2.a3 e6 3.d4 Nf6 4.e4 Nxe4 5.Nh3 Na6 6.Bxa6 bxa6 7.O-O h5 8.Nc3 Nxc3 9.bxc3 Bd6 10.Qf3 Qh4 11.a4 e5 12.dxe5 Be7 13.Qxd5 Rb8 14.Be3 Bxh3 15.gxh3 Qxh3 16.Bxa7 Rb2 17.Rfd1 Rxc2 18.Qa8+ Bd8 19.Qxd8#  1-0
```

Is early e4 is bound to lost concerning Bird's Theory.

I felt to do, to free up space for King and to start with Gambit [or] Attack from my side. And I had opened it up for Attack.

```
[fen "rnbqkb1r/ppp2ppp/4pn2/3p4/3PPP2/P7/1PP3PP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq e3 0 1"]
```

And does this has any name `1.f4 d5 2.a3 e6 3.d4 Nf6 4.e4 Nxe4` by technique wise or is just a spoof.

Comment: A general rule of thumb: if it just drops a pawn or even more material for no good reason, it's just a blunder and not a named opening system. More specifically regarding this question, an early e4 is not what White intends when playing Bird's opening. Also, you shouldn't aim to open up for YOUR king in the opening. Get YOUR king to safety, and open up in front of your OPPONENT'S king. The goal of chess is to checkmate; it's not to get checkmated by your opponent, which is the only thing opening up in front of your own king in the opening could accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is early e4 is bound to lost concerning Bird's Theory.

Yes, 4. e4 is a bad move giving black a pawn for free. In usual gambit lines you gain something (e.g. lead in development, better pawn structure...) for the sacrificed pawn, but here, black's position is very solid with no weaknesses. I don't see how e4 gives you any attack.

> I felt to do, to free up space for King...

You don't free up space for the king, but for the minor pieces...

The bird opening/reversed stonewall that you play here is not really suited for quick development and usually it is wise to keep the position closed at the start of the game. If you want quick development, play something normal, like 1. e4. For instance a somewhat similar position like you got in the game you can have in some French lines (and with equal number of pawns).

A typical set-up for the reversed stonewall that you played would look like:

```
8/8/8/8/3P1P2/2PBPN2/PP1N2PP/R1BQ1RK1 w - - 1 1
```

The dark squared bishop on c1 is typically weak in this opening and may be devloped via d2-e1-h4 or sometimes to a3. If you are allowed, you can try to play e4 later after preparation and without losing a pawn.

Regarding the rest of the game:

- 2. a3: It is unclear what the idea behind this move is. I mean, you play 1. f4, then 2. a3 and on move 4 you suddenly realize that you need to develop your pieces...
- 12. dxe5: You got lucky that black played 11. ... e5. Here 12. fxe5 seems stronger as you attack the bishop on d6 and at the same time have the threat of Qxf7+